# $\mathfrak{h}(\mathcal{G}^{\Delta^1})$ is the category of commutative squares in $\mathfrak{h}\mathcal{G}$

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

This is related to the question [Homotopy category of a symmetric monoidal $(\infty,1)$-category is symmetric monoidal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640281/homotopy-category-of-a-symmetric-monoidal-infty-1-category-is-symmetric-mon/4640873?noredirect=1#comment9796341_4640873).

Let us fix an $(\infty,0)$-category $\mathcal{G}$ (a Kan complex). We want to look at the homotopy category $\mathfrak{h}(\mathcal{G}^{\Delta^1})$, which has as its set of objects all natural transformations $\Delta^1 \to \mathcal{G}$ (by the Yoneda Lemma elements in $\mathcal{G}_1$) and as its set of morphisms the natural transformations $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1 \to \mathcal{G}$. A natural transformation $\eta \colon \Delta^1 \times \Delta^1 \to \mathcal{G}$ breaks down to the information of a square with faces $\eta(\text{id}, d^1), \eta(\text{id}, d^0), \eta(d^1, \text{id}), \eta(d^0, \text{id})$ depicted by the [diagram](https://q.uiver.app/?q=WzAsNCxbMCwwLCJcXGJ1bGxldCJdLFsyLDAsIlxcYnVsbGV0Il0sWzAsMiwiXFxidWxsZXQiXSxbMiwyLCJcXGJ1bGxldCJdLFswLDIsIlxcZXRhKFxcdGV4dHtpZH0sZF4xKSIsMl0sWzIsMywiXFxldGEoZF4wLFxcdGV4dHtpZH0pIiwyXSxbMSwzLCJcXGV0YShcXHRleHR7aWR9LGReMCkiXSxbMCwxLCJcXGV0YShkXjEsXFx0ZXh0e2lkfSkiXV0=). I want to prove that by passing to the homotopy category $\mathfrak{h}\mathcal{G}$ any such diagram yields a commutative square. The claim would follow, if we had a diagonal morphism (or two homotopical diagonal morphisms) yielding two triangles, such that each given triangle may also be filled by a $2$-simplex. Pictorially,
[diagram2](https://q.uiver.app/?q=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). Of course, by means of horn filling conditions we may always obtain such a diagram, however, it is not clear (at least to me) why any two such diagonals for the respective triangles must coincide up to homotopy. So:

> How to prove that morphisms in $\mathfrak{h}(\mathcal{G}^{\Delta^1})$ are really just commutative squares in $\mathfrak{h}\mathcal{G}$, or put differently, how to prove that we have an isomorphism of categories $\mathfrak{h}(\mathcal{G}^{\Delta^1}) \cong \mathfrak{h}\mathcal{G}^{\mathfrak{h}\Delta^1}$ (note that $\mathfrak{h}\Delta^1$ is precisely the category with two objects and one non-identity morphism)?

Edit: If $\mathcal{G}$ is a Kan complex, then we define
$$\mathfrak{h}\mathcal{G}$$ to be the category which has as its set of objects $\mathcal{G}_0$ and as its set of morphisms $\mathcal{G}_1$ modulo the relation below. Domain and codomain maps are given by $\text{dom}= \mathcal{G}(d^1), \text{cod} = \mathcal{G}(d^0)$ and composition is induced by the horn filling properties of $\mathcal{G}$, that is, if $f \colon x \to y,g \colon y \to z$ are in $\mathcal{G}_1$, then there exists a $2$-simplex $\sigma \in \mathcal{G}_2$ so that $d_0(\sigma) = g, d_2(\sigma) = f$ and we define $gf = d_1(\sigma)$. More precisely, $\mathfrak{h} \colon \text{sSet} \to \text{Cat}$ is left adjoint to the usual nerve functor.

Comment: How do you define $\mathfrak{h}G$? This is quite crucial. There are a few different equivalent models of the same thing, in some of them your question is trivial and in others it is not

Comment: @FShrike I have added the corresponding definition I am using to the question. Thanks for pointing out potential ambiguities.

Comment: I don’t think this claim is true. There’s probably a counterexample using the 2-sphere.

Comment: @ZhenLin How is it justified then to define an $\infty$-natural transformation as a homotopy $\mathcal{G} \to \widetilde{\mathcal{G}}^{\Delta^1}$? Isn't this supposed to always yield a natural transformation when passing to homotopy categories?

Comment: What is true is that the canonical comparison from the homotopy category of the arrow category to the arrow category of the homotopy category is surjective and full.

Comment: Also I was mistaken – for ∞-groupoids the comparison is an equivalence, because from the perspective of an ∞-groupoid $\Delta^1$ is contractible.

Comment: There is an equivalence of categories between what you have and the "fundamental groupoid" category of the Kan complex. In this category the arrows $\eta(d_0,1)$ and $\eta(d_1,1)$ will be the same. $\eta(1,d_0)$ and $\eta(1,d_1)$ will also be the same

Comment: The definition of the homotopy category appears to be wrong: the composition map is not well-defined, since it depends on arbitrary choices.  It appears that instead one must take as morphisms equivalence classes of 1-simplices modulo homotopy relative boundary, not the 1-simplices themselves.

Comment: @DmitriP. That's true! The set of 1-morphisms is given by taking equivalence classes of 1-simplices, my bad on that part.

Comment: @h3fr43nd: Now that we resolved this issue, is your main question not answered by the observation that a simplicial map $η\colon Δ^1×Δ^1→G$ picks out two 2-simplices in $G$ with the same 1st face (the diagonal), which indeed provides the diagonal morphism that you were asking for in your main question?

Comment: @DmitriP. This is precisely what I am not seeing yet. How does $\eta$ pick out two $2$-simplices?

Comment: @h3fr43nd: Example 21.10 in my notes (https://dmitripavlov.org/notes/topology.pdf) contains a detailed description of Δ^1⨯Δ^1.

Comment: @DmitriP. I see, so what you are saying is that any natural transformation $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1 \to \mathcal{G}$ gives rise to a functor $\mathfrak{h}(\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1) \to \mathfrak{h}\mathcal{G}$ and this may then be identified as a commutative square in $\mathfrak{h}\mathcal{G}$, is that correct?

Comment: @h3fr43nd: Yes, that's exactly right.